# How to prove that a morphism of schemes preserves the surjectivity of ring endomorphisms?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $\left(T,\mathcal{O}_{T}\right)$ and $\left(S,\mathcal{O}_{S}\right)$ be schemes and $f:T\rightarrow S$. $U\subset S$ and $V\subset T$ are some open sets that correspond to the definition of $f^{*}:\mathcal{O}_{S}^{n}\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{T}^{n}$.

I refer to the following definition of $f^{*}$ (with $X$ instead of $S$ and $Y$ instead of $T$):

> For all pairs $\left(U,V\right)$ formed from open sets $U$ of $X$ and $V$ of $Y$ such that $f\left(V\right)\subset U$, exists a morphism of rings $f^{*}:\mathcal{O}_{X}\left(U\right)\rightarrow\mathcal{O}_{Y}\left(V\right)$, with the requirement that if $U$ and $U^{\prime}$ are two open sets of $X$, and $V$ and $V^{\prime}$ are two open sets of $Y$ with $V^{\prime}\subset V$, $f\left(V\right)\subset U$ and $f\left(V^{\prime}\right)\subset U^{\prime}$, then the diagram

[image]

> commutes.

How can it be proved that
$$
q\left(U\right):\mathcal{O}_{S}^{n}\left(U\right)\rightarrow\mathcal{O}_{S}^{n}\left(U\right)\textrm{ surjective}\Rightarrow \left(f^{*}q\right)\left(U\right):\mathcal{O}_{T}^{n}\left(V\right)\rightarrow\mathcal{O}_{T}^{n}\left(V\right)\textrm{ surjective}?
$$
Here $q$ is an endomorphism between $\mathcal{O}_{S}^{n}$ and $\mathcal{O}_{S}$-module $\mathcal{O}_{S}^{n}$.

I already proved the converse.

Am I missing something here?

Edit: it looks like I should use the fact that $f^{*}\left(\mathcal{O}_{S}^{n}\right)=\mathcal{O}_{T}^{n}$ (vs. merely $f^{*}\left(\mathcal{O}_{S}^{n}\right)\subseteq \mathcal{O}_{T}^{n}$).

Comment: what kind of map is $q$ ?

Comment: @KonstantinArdakov In the framework of the theory, $q$ is an endomorphism between $\mathcal{O}_{S}^{n}$-modules $\mathcal{O}_{S}^{n}$.

Comment: Use stalk-exactness and the fact that tensor product is right exact.

Comment: Stalk-exactness doesn't work here *a priori* since we don't have surjections of sheaves. Also it is often much more natural not to work with stalks.

Comment: @Jake: You have confused the definitions of $f^\#$ (sheaf part of a morphism) and $f^*$ (pullback functor associated to a morphism).

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I see what you mean. I have checked, and it seems that my lecture notes don't use $f^{\sharp}$ anywhere and use $f^{*}$ where Hartshorne uses $f^{\sharp}$.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Also, it looks like "sheaf part of morphism" is not used in the lecture notes, so there is no contradiction. (I took a part of the definition exactly out of lecture notes, so perhaps the thing is that there is a subtle difference with the usual definition.)

Comment: The question as stated doesn't make any sense. Either the lecture notes have an error (doubtful), or you have confused notations etc.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Reconciling your reformulation and my problem statement, I see that I should have wrote $q(U)$ instead of $q$, but $S$ and $T$ are indeed sheaves. The $V\subseteq f^{-1}\left(U\right)$ in your problem statement corresponds to me referring to a definition. The question's notation is same as that of lecture notes, and I'm sure I was otherwise precise in it, although I omitted a lot of hopefully irrelevant data (which is about a page long).

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Cross-referencing the question and the lecture notes, it looks like while $S$ and $T$ are sheaves, the matter of the question indeed falls back to that of ringed spaces. But that should be fine, as a sheaf is a particular case of a ringed space, and none of the sheaf properties are violated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is unclear as stated (what is $q$? what's the purpose of $s,t$? what does "correspond to the definition of $f^{*}:\mathcal{O}_{S}^{n}\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{T}^{n}$" mean?). So here is what perhaps was meant:

Set $f : T \to S$ be a morphism of arbitrary ringed spaces. Let $q : \mathcal{O}_S^n \to \mathcal{O}_S^n$ be a homomorphism of $\mathcal{O}_S$-modules such that $q(U) : \mathcal{O}_S(U)^n \to \mathcal{O}_S(U)^n$ is surjective for some open subset $U$. Let $V \subseteq f^{-1}(U)$ be some open subset. Why is then $(f^* q)(V) : \mathcal{O}_S(V)^n \to \mathcal{O}_S(V)^n$ surjective?

First, I claim that actually $q|_U : \mathcal{O}_U^n \to \mathcal{O}_U^n$ is an isomorphism. In fact, $q(U)$ is an isomorphism since it is a surjective endomorphism of a f.g. free module. The determinant of $q(U)$ is therefore a unit global section of $\mathcal{O}_U$. This stays a unit global section if we restrict to open subsets $V$ of $U$, which shows that $q(V)$ is also an isomorphism.

Let $f_U$ denote the corestriction $f^{-1}(U) \to U$. Since $(f_U)^*$ is a functor, it maps isomorphisms to isomorphisms. Thus, $(f_U)^* q|_U : \mathcal{O}_{f^{-1}(U)}^n \to \mathcal{O}_{f^{-1}(U)}^n$ is an isomorphism. Now we may restrict this to an open subset $V \subseteq f^{-1}(U)$ and take sections on $V$ to see that $(f^* q)(V)$ is an isomorphism.

(Notice that we really need isomorphisms for this kind of reasoning; epimorphisms don't restrict to epimorphisms on sections, since  sheaf cohomology is an obstruction for this.)